# ¿Cómo guardo un parámetro que recibo de un proveedor en otro parámetro para luego mostrarlo en un viewbag para hacer un post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Haciendo uso de mi controlador, en mi *get* capturo el `idprovedor`, pero no sé cómo pasarlo al atributo `idProv` para así mandarlo en un `viewbag` y hacer un *post*.

```
public ActionResult Create(int idProveedor)
{
    var Proveedor = db.Proveedor.Where(x => x.Id_Proveedor== idProveedor).FirstOrDefault();

    ViewBag.Proveedor =Proveedor; 

    var Producto = db.Productos.Select(x => new {   IdProd = x.Id_Prod,   Nombre_Prod = x.Nombre_Prod  }).ToList();

    ViewBag.Producto = new MultiSelectList(Producto, "IdProd", "Nombre_Prod");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id_Compra,Cantidad_Prod,
Precio_Compra,Fecha_Entrega,IdProd, IdProv,Id_Proveedor,Id_Prod")] CompraDeProductos compraDeProductos)
                                   /*^^^^*/                                                                     
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       db.CompraDeProductos.Add(compraDeProductos);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index","Productos");
   }

   return View(compraDeProductos);
}
```

Comment: Es simple.. reemplaza tu x.Id_Prod por IdProv = idProveedor en tu select.

Comment: Pero en Idproveedor estoy asignándole la q estoy obteniendo, puedo así ganarla directamente en idprov

Comment: Asignándola? Dónde? En el Where?

Comment: Modificaron la explicación quizá me entienda